# OpenCV compiling error after using anaconda to install opencv

Tags: python, c++, opencv, ubuntu, anaconda

I have opencv 3.1 (built from source) worked perfectly fine in Ubuntu. However after I installed the python version of opencv 3.2 from anaconda (conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0), I am having following warning/errors:

> **/usr/bin/ld: warning: libjpeg.so.9, needed by
>   //home/sss/anaconda3/lib/libtiff.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or
>   -rpath-link)**
>
> //home/sss/anaconda3/lib/libtiff.so.5: undefined reference to
>   'jpeg_finish_decompress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
>
> //home/sss/anaconda3/lib/libtiff.so.5: undefined reference to
>   'jpeg_set_quality@LIBJPEG_9.0'
>
> ...

Here's my cmake file which I followed some online source.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( test )

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "    library path: ${OpenCV_LIB_DIR}")

include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable( testcv main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( testcv ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

> -- OpenCV library status:
>
> --     version: 3.1.0
>
> --     libraries:
>
> opencv_xphoto;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_tracking;opencv_text;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_structured_light;opencv_stereo;opencv_saliency;opencv_rgbd;opencv_reg;opencv_plot;opencv_optflow;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_hdf;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_face;opencv_dpm;opencv_dnn;opencv_datasets;opencv_ccalib;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_aruco;opencv_videostab;opencv_videoio;opencv_video;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_shape;opencv_photo;opencv_objdetect;opencv_ml;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_highgui;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_core;opencv_calib3d
>
> --     include path: /usr/local/include/opencv;/usr/local/include
>
> --     library path: /usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib
>
> -- Configuring done
>
> -- Generating done
>
> -- Build files have been written to: /home/sss/Project/OpenCV/Test01/build

All the opencv libs are inside "/usr/local/lib", and there's only one file "libippicv.a" in the folder "/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib". And I tried to add SET(OpenCV_LIB_DIR "/usr/local/lib"), the compiling error remains.

my main.cpp contains only two opencv lines:

```
Mat image;
image = imread("lena.jpg",1);
```

and if I **comment the 2nd line (imread)**, build would be successful.

It seems somehow install opencv inside anaconda made some outside changes to the system, but what are they? How can I get my opencv back to work again?

**UPDATE**

I found a temporary way by redirecting the link:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

But what was changed before? and How to do it correctly in cmake?

**UPDATE**

It stops working again. Though I can build it, once I run the program it keep asking ligjpeg.so.9.

"error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

How to solve it?

Comment: Ok, so you are talking about having 3.1 but installed 3.2 then you show that your `cmake` clearly finds `3.1` instead of `3.2`. If you do not need 3.1 I suggest you remove it and go with 3.2.  Multiple versions of any library that provides cmake-modules (files with the extension `*.cmake`) can create a mess. Have you tried setting `OpenCV_DIR` variable to the  directory that contains 3.2? (use `set(OpenCV_DIR ...)` to do that) What Anaconda has probably done is (given the error message) upgrade some libraries which are required by this and that OpenCV module.

Comment: You can use `readelf -d <opencv-module.so>` to check the dependencies of the given shared library. Do that on both versions to see the differences in terms of dependencies.

Comment: @rbaleksandar, I found all "/usr/local/lib" only contains libopencv*3.1, while all the libopencv*3.2 are inside "~/anaconda3/lib". I also found jpeg*, tiff*.so, were added to the same folder "~/anaconda3/lib" only after I instructed "conda install opencv"; while original ones (jpeg* and tiff*) can only be found under "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"

Comment: @rbaleksandar There's libjpeg.so.9 under "anaconda3/lib", but libjpeg.so.8 under "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu". Can this be the problem? Is there anyway I can make the compiler to direct to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"?